# Android WebView and web browser opening ftp url link

Tags: android, http, ftp, android-webview

I have a FTP URL (an example url is used below) which needs to be displayed by my app. My app has the option to display this file in a WebView or to open this in the device's web browser.

If I open the above FTP url in the WebView, the webView shows the error net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME . If I open the above url in the web browser,it crashes the app with the error log (snippet shown below).

...
 Android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt 
...

It seems that the android WebView or web browser are unable to handle such links. However, if I change the above url to http:// instead of ftp:// ( http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/standards/RFC/rfc959.txt ) both the preview and browser options work. So, my question is do the Android WebView and Web browser not support ftp:// protocol ? Is there any official documentation for evidence ?

Comment: You tried to start your app with an intent?  Did you  try WebView.loadUrl()  ? Or did you try that url directly in a browser?

Comment: I use WebView.loadUrl()  for loading the url within the app. For opening the url in the web browser, I use the intent.

Comment: Please try my suggestion. You are not even commenting on it.

Comment: Yes, I'm already doing what you've suggested. Please read my comment above.